# Dynamically updating the view after adding to a database with Angular 5 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a service which looks like this

```
export class EmployeeService {
  selectedEmployee: Employee = null;
  employeesGET;
  employeeChange: BehaviorSubject<Employee> = new BehaviorSubject<Employee>(null);

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { 
     this.employeesGET = this.http.get('/api')
  }

  employeePOST(employee) {
      this.http.post('/api', employee)
          .subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res);
  })
}
```

In one component, I get the array of employees and display them:

```
getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeeService.employeesGET
      .subscribe((employees) => {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.employees.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0);} );
        this.displayedEmployees = this.employees.slice(
          this.carouselStartIndex, 
          this.carouselStartIndex + this.employeesInCarousel)
      });
  }
```

And I also allow the user to add employees to the database by the post function in the service above. 
Once a user has added another employee, what do I need to implement to make the view update dynamically? Do I need to create a new get request or can I somehow use the one that first gets the data?

Comment: if somebody add a new employee from wherever, you want that the view automatically updated to all people which have the view open?

Comment: Yeah. I want all views currently open to update when a new employee is added to the database

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques to do this:

1. Polling and Long-Polling
2. Forever Frame
3. HTML5 Server-sent Events
4. Websockets protocol

There a [pluralsight course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/socket-io-building-real-time-applications) where you can find more info an a example of each one.